# remote python client failing to reach couchbase server

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, couchbase

I have a couchbase 6.0 server running on linode and I'm using the python SDK to insert data into my couchbase bucket. When run directly on the Linode server, my data gets inserted.
However, when I run my code from a remote machine I get network error:

```
CouchbaseNetworkError, CouchbaseTransientError): <RC=0x2C[The remote host refused the connection.
```

I have ports 8091, 8092, 8093, 8094 open on linode.

```py
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator

# linode ip: 1.2.3.4
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://1.2.3.4:8094')
cluster.authenticate(PasswordAuthenticator('admin', 'password'))
bucket = cluster.open_bucket('test_bucket')
bucket.upsert('1',{"foo":"bar"})
```

My code executes when run on the server with `couchbase://localhost` but it fails when run from a remote machine. is there any port or configuration I am missing?

Comment: "I have ports 8091, 8092, 8093 open" and then `cluster = Cluster('couchbase://1.2.3.4:8094')` - that could be the issue right there. Also, I'm wondering why you're using port 8094 there anyway, since 8091 is normally specified.

Comment: Thanks for that I have 4 open as well. I ll correct it

Comment: There's a tool you might want to try called SDK Doctor - https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sdk-doctor - it can often diagnose these kind of issues.

Comment: I am sure it's gonna come in handy in the future. thanks for pointing out this tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client-to-node: Between any clients/app-servers/SDKs and all nodes of each cluster they require access to.

Unencrypted*: 8091-8096, 11210, 11211

Encrypted: 18091-18096†††, 11207

using ports 11210 and 11211 worked for me. [source](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html)